# How to split an array into interval chunks

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an enum like this:

```
enum MyEnum {
   elem1 = 100,
   elem2,
   elem3
   elem4,

   elem5 = 200
   elem6,
   elem7,

   elem8 = 300
   elem9
}
```

Is there an elegant way (using `reduce` or other array methods) to split this into separate interval chunks?

Expected result:

```
[ [100, 101, 102, 103] , [200, 201, 202], [300,301] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the number from your `enum` and group consecutive numbers in arrays.

```
enum MyEnum {
  elem1 = 100,
    elem2 = 101,
    elem3 = 102,
    elem4 = 103,

    elem5 = 200,
    elem6 = 201,
    elem7 = 202,

    elem8 = 300,
    elem9 = 301
}

Object.entries(MyEnum)
  .filter(([x]) => !isNaN(parseInt(x)))
  .map(([, key]) => MyEnum[key])
  .reduce((r, val, i, a) => {
    if (!i || val !== a[i - 1] + 1) r.push([]);
    r[r.length - 1].push(val);
    return r;
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the tidiest solution, but maybe it helps:

```
const getEnumValues = (enm: any) => {
    let els: number[][] = [];
    
    for(let curr in enm) {
        // When looping over Enums you get both the keys and the values,
        // so we omit every value that is not a number
        if(isNaN(curr as any)) continue;
    
        const numValue = parseInt(curr);
        
        if(els.length != 0) { 
            // If there are alread elements inside, get the latest batch
            const lastBatch = els[els.length - 1];
            // Check if the latest number in the latest batch is the same as the 
            // current num - 1
            if(lastBatch[lastBatch.length - 1] != numValue - 1) {
                // If not, create a new batch
                els.push([numValue]);
            } else {
                // If they match, add to the current batch
                lastBatch.push(numValue);
            }
        } else { 
            // If the elements are empty until now, 
            // just pass an array with the current value
            els.push([numValue]);
        }
    }

    return els;
}

console.log(getEnumValues(MyEnum));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how your Enum will look like in JS. You can use the `reduce` below that for your question.

I used `%10 === 0` but you can also replace it with checking the increment from the last pushed value to be `1`.

```js
const MyEnum = {
  "100": "elem1",
  "101": "elem2",
  "102": "elem3",
  "103": "elem4",
  "200": "elem5",
  "201": "elem6",
  "202": "elem7",
  "300": "elem8",
  "301": "elem9",
  "elem1": 100,
  "elem2": 101,
  "elem3": 102,
  "elem4": 103,
  "elem5": 200,
  "elem6": 201,
  "elem7": 202,
  "elem8": 300,
  "elem9": 301
}

const result = Object.keys(MyEnum).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const num = Number(curr);
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
        num % 10 === 0 ? prev.push([num]) : prev[prev.length - 1].push(num)
    }
    return prev
}, []) // as number[][]
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice solution. But fails if value is `110`

Comment: @User863 I just wanted to show a solution with `reduce` as asked in the question, you can change the condition to  check for a single increment from the last element of `prev[prev.length - 1]` to just achieve what others did as I've mentioned in the answer